# Service worker not adding auth header after force refresh

Tags: service-worker

I understand that service workers will not apply the first load after a force refresh due to cache issues, but for those that are relying on service workers to intercept requests and add auth tokens to the header, how is this behavior acceptable? Right now my API requests fail after a force refresh and will only work after another non-force refresh. Is this really the state of service workers (unusable) or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

Service workers are intended to be treated as progressive enhancement, and it's not a good plan to ship a web app that will only work when a service worker is in control.

That means coming up with alternative ways of adding in authorization that do not rely on service worker interception to avoid the issue you describe.